# How to use 'distinct' in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js, psql

I have the following SQL function that I'm trying to call in Sequelize.

```
SELECT messID
FROM users
WHERE userID in userIds
GROUP BY messID
having count(distinct userID) = userIds.length
```

`userIds` is an array of id's. I currently have the following so far but I'm having trouble with the last line.

```
Users.findNewID = async function (userIds) {
  const newID = await Users.findOne({
    where: {
      [Op.contains]: userIds
    },
    group: messID,
  });

  return newID;
};
```

But I'm not sure how to use distinct on the `having` line.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize is not about complex aggregating queries it mostly about working with models that are mapped to tables (that's why it's called ORM).

Just use plain SQL-query with parameters like this:

```js
const newIDResult = await sequelize.query(`
SELECT messID
FROM users
WHERE userID in $userIds
GROUP BY messID
having count(distinct userID) = $userIdsLength
`, {
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
  bind: {
            userIds,
            userIdsLength: userIds.length
        }
 });
```